# Authentication failure for eu-central-1 (Frankfurt) AWS

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS Ruby v2 sdk pre-release. The scripts for EC2 and S3 services which were working smoothly for eu-west-1 are not working for eu-central-1. I was getting the following exception:

```
AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (Aws::EC2::Errors::AuthFailure)
```

After a short query, I identified it was due the fact that eu-central-1 supports only Signature Version 4. That's ok. As recommended, I added `s3_signature_version: v4` in my `config.yml`. Then I started to get a new exception:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.3/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:160:in `rescue in block in apply_options': invalid configuration option `:s3_signature_version' (ArgumentError)
```

So now I have 2 questions.

- What is the problem with `s3_signature_version: v4` in `config.yml`?
- And what is the similar signature version 4 configuration for Ec2 need to be added?

Comment: `config.yml` was used in older AWS SDK. The one you are using is aws-sdk-core which is the newer one. You need to find out similar option for aws-sdk-core.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Does specific file name matter? I am using a generic way to retrieve configuration from a file. So far I did not see any effect of different file names. aws-config.yml is my authentic file. `config_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),"aws-config.yml")\n
Aws.config = YAML.load(File.read(config_file)).inject({}) { |h,(k,v)| h.merge(k.to_sym => v) } `

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby/tree/master/aws-sdk-core/spec/aws/signers Seems like they have added this feature to aws-sdk-ruby. Could you try installing/updating latest version of aws-sdk-core gem and then try. It might support signature V4 out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

If you update to version 2.0.5 of aws-sdk-core, then it will default to signature version 4. To force an older version of aws-sdk-core to use sigv4, pass `signature_version: 'v4'` to your client constructor.

Comment: How to update the version of aws-sdk-core on ubuntu? Please let me know.